# Enter for message telegram bot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Currently, I am developing telegram bot to send message to all member in group chat.
My difficulty right now I cannot make a message with enter.

I already tried adding `\n` however it wont worked.

this is what I want for example.

message:

```
Good morning,

Have good day.
```

when the message need to have enter it cannot send with enter. the result will be like this.

```
Good morning,/n/n Have good day.
```

does anyone know how telegram read enter which can be used in python code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to send multiline messages, you can use the `multiline strings` like this:

```
bot.send_message('chat-id', """
Good morning,

Have good day.
""")
```

and enable the markup also, so that it dose not interfere the empty lines.